# different sets of variables for different Makefile target

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I am trying to add some flexibility into an existing Makefile which currently only compiles for one architecture. I assume that prior to my changes 'all' was the default target - that's the first target without a dot, it's defined somewhere in the middle of the huge file.

I've added

```
default_action: stm32f4target
```

on top of the file and

```
stm32f4target: all
```

to the bottom of the file, I assume this wraps the 'all' inside my new default 'stm32f4target' task. Still works.

Now I want to make an existing variable definition

```
USE_FPU = yes
```

conditional to my target, so I change it to

```
stm32f4target: USE_FPU = yes
```

but this breaks everything: I am still invoking make without parameters and I assume my new stm32f4target is the default target. I get a message from my C compiler that a macro related to FPU is redefined, which means that my last change has changed the behavior of the Makefile which I was not expecting. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, what's your actual make system? All handwritten? How are the `CFLAGS` expanded, when `ifeq($USE_FPU,yes)`? (debugging makefiles is a hard job, I know well :-( )

Comment: If you just want to change the default goal (without introducing new targets) you can use the [`.DEFAULT_GOAL`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_002eDEFAULT_005fGOAL-_0028define-default-goal_0029) variable for that. So `.DEFAULT_GOAL := stm32f4target` for example.

Comment: Was `USE_FPU` set to yes by default and you are now trying to scope that to just that one target? If so that will change the default behaviour of the make process. Which target isn't working at this point? The new one? The old default `all` target?

Comment: (added info into the question) I am invoking make without specifing the target and I assume that my new stm32f4target is the default target. I've tried 'make -d' and it confirms that stm32f4target is the new default I am invoking

Comment: Yes all hand-written, yes

ifeq ($(USE_FPU),)
  USE_FPU = no
endif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way in standard make to conditionally set variables during make execution. But as a work-around, you can use a recursive make invocation with that variable set on the command line:

```
stm32f4target:
        $(MAKE) all USE_FPU=yes
```

Command line definitions overwrite Makefile variables, so you can leave a default USE_FPU=no in your Makefile, if you like.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [gnu-make](/questions/tagged/gnu-make), you can assign a value to a variable using the `eval` function

```
stm32f4target: 
    $(eval USE_FPU=yes)
```